# I Can not get logged in user ID in facebook application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-page

I am working on facebook fanpage application, I have setup the application and add it in my fan page. The problem is that only I can see my facebook id but when I access my application from different facebook account I can see 0 instead of logged in userId, Does anybody can help in this issue, Why I am getting 0 instead of logged in userID?. Your help in this matter will be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided some ocde

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the permission from user since facebook only provide the user id on fanpage if your app has the user permissions. Some developers used this approach for validation if they got user id they do the rest processing otherwise redirects the user to allow page.

Answer (score 0):

In the signed_request your user ID will show up because you're the developer of the app.  However, a normal user's ID will not be seen.

To be able to get the user id of a random user viewing your page, your app will need to request permissions/authentication from them to provide you their basic information.  See: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for more information on how to get a user to login. And specifically for PHP see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getUser/